# Delete all occurrences of double backslash

Tags: regex, vim

How do I delete all occurrences of `\\` from cursor position to the end of file?

What I tried:

`:%s/\\//g` deletes single `\` and in all the file.

`:g#\\#$d` does not really work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `:.,$s/\\\\//g`

- The first `\` will escape the second `\`, so you need to use 4 to get 2 literal backslashes.
- Thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7598188/703229), I learned that the `%` in `:%s` is shorthand for `1,$` (or the first line, to the end of the file).  If we change this to `.,$`, our substitution will run from the current position to the end of the file.

Comment: worked like a charm! :) So 4 backslashes because you escape 2nd with 1st and 4th with 3rd?

Comment: Exactly..[a backslash is almost always an escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) (because if you want to match a reserved character like `/` the expression would be [`/\//`](http://regex101.com/r/tE6cM8/1)), so `\x = x` where `x` is any character.