# vim search and replace from the current location of the cursor to a specified token

Tags: search, vim, replace

I'd like a vi command that would replace from the location of the cursor to a given token.     For example starting with

```
 word  blah blah     =(
```

I'd like if I locate the cursor at the space after `word` to be able to replace everything between the cursor and the equality sign with, say, #,
obtaining

```
  word#(
```

I'm sure if I could understand [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598133/vim-global-search-replace-starting-from-the-cursor-position), I could figure it out, but that thread is much more complicated than what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
cf=#<esc>
```

The `c` command is "change", which deletes text and puts you in insert mode. It takes a motion just like every other operator. `f=` is a motion that jumps your cursor to the next occurrence of '='. This works with any other character to, for example, `fa` will jump to the next 'a', `fb` will jump the the next 'b', etc. After that, you end up in insert mode, and can enter `#`. Then just hit `<esc>` to return to normal mode.

You can do the same thing with more advanced "tokens" by using `/foo` instead of `f=`. For example, if you'd like to change until the next occurrence of `=(` instead of the next occurrence of `=`, you could do

```
c/=(<cr>#<esc>
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `f`/`F` and `t`/`T` only work on the current line.  To do this across multiple lines you need to use a search (`/`).

Answer (score 3):

Unless there are other `=` chars between the cursor and the desired `=`, you can use `cf=#<Esc>`.

`cf=` deletes from the cursor until the first `=` (inclusive), and places you in insert mode.